# Program Factorial in Java with a lookup table

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, factorial

In an effort to improve my programming I am trying out this problem in Java. I have looked everywhere for an elegant solution and cant find it.

> Write a program which takes a single argument, computes the factorial and prints the 
>   value on the screen.Also the program must be interactive instead of terminating after
>   each computation and that it uses a table of previous values to improve the performance.

**How do I make it so that in the method calls it checks if it has already computed the factorial for a value? Any other improvements to this code to make it more readable or efficient are also appreciated.**

This is what I have written so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = 0;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    HashMap cache = new HashMap();

    while(1 == 1){
        do{
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter the number you would like to factor");
                input = reader.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e){
                reader.next();
            }
        } while(input <= 0);

        if(cache.get(input) != null){
            System.out.println("Found in cache");
            System.out.println(input + "! = " + cache.get(input));
        } 
        else {
            cache.put(input, factorialRecursively(input));
            System.out.println(input + "! = " + factorialRecursively(input));
        }

    }   

}       

public static int factorialIteratively(int a) throws InputMismatchException {
    int temp = 1;
    while(a > 0){
        temp = temp * a;
        a--;
    }
    return temp;
}

public static int factorialRecursively(int a) throws InputMismatchException{
    if (a == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return a * factorialRecursively(a-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: you arent satisfied with you solution??? but why? it is already efficient

Comment: As you are using a `int` you can only have about 11! or 12! before it overflows.  I suggest you put all these in an array on start up and you won't need to maintain a collection or compute anything.

Comment: This is the solution that I came up with... I just know their is a better and cleaner solution and would like to know it.

Comment: why are you making 2 functions? you can do the same by using only 1 factorial function.

Comment: Here's a related question that deals more with data type limitations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712480/factorial-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'll give it a shot. Let me first give you the full code answer, and get into each change in details:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = 0;

    try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in)) {

        Map<Integer, Integer> cache = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        cache.put(1, 1);

        while (true) {
            do {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the number you would like to factor");
                    input = reader.nextInt();
                } catch (InputMismatchException e){
                    reader.next();
                    input = 0;
                }
            } while(input <= 0);

            if(cache.get(input) != null) {
                System.out.println("Found in cache");
                System.out.println(input + "! = " + cache.get(input));
            } 
            else {
                int result = factorialRecursively(input, cache);
                System.out.println(input + "! = " + result);
            }
        }   
    }
}       

public static int factorialRecursively(int limit, Map<Integer, Integer> cache) {

    int cacheSize = cache.size();
    if (cacheSize < limit) {
        int nextFactorial = cacheSize + 1; 
        System.out.println("Calculating and caching " + nextFactorial + "!");
        cache.put(nextFactorial, cache.get(cacheSize) * nextFactorial); 
        return factorialRecursively(limit, cache);
    }
    else {
        return cache.get(limit);
    }
}
```

1) the direct answer to your question: "how to make sure the method that calculates the factorial, checks whether it has already computed the factorial for a value". So I stuck to the recursive approach, although you could also implement the iterative version using the same concept.
Basically, the idea is to pass a reference of the results cache to the method itself (the `Map<Integer, Integer> cache` argument), so it becomes responsible for storing the resulting computed factorial at each multiplication step, and not only once the full factorial has been computed. To do so, I made the method compute the factorial from the bottom up, and not the other way round. We store the smallest factorial in the cache as starting point (`cache.put(1, 1);`). I added an output message which shows when a factorial is calculated and cached, and by testing the code you can see that one particular factorial only ever gets calculated and stored once.

2) the use of `Map<Integer, Integer> cache = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();` instead of `HashMap cache = new HashMap();`.
a) Since Java 1.5, collections have been made generic (long story, outside the scope here), and when referenced should be parameterized. So here we're saying, I want to store Integer values (computed factorials), that I can access with Integer keys (factorial source).
b) The reason the code compiles and allows us to use integer primitives and not Integer class objects, is because of a mechanism named auto-boxing which seamlessly wraps integer primitives into Integer objects, and vice-versa. Again, out of scope, but one should be aware of it.
c) The functionality we are after here is that of the `Map` interface, which `HashMap` happens to be an implementation of. Unless the referencing code relies on `HashMap` specific methods (unlikely), it is good practice to declare your variables as the corresponding collection interface (like `List` for `ArrayList` etc.), not as the implementation class.

3) InputMismatchException is only thrown by the Scanner class, and therefore does not need to be thrown by any code that does not call the `Scanner` `nextInt()` method.

4) the use of `true` instead of `1 == 1`. Equivalent in practice, but using a boolean value is more readable.

5) Only calling the `factorialRecursively` method once. Your code calls the method twice, which is unnecessary. If you're after efficiency and elegance, you should only call the method once and store its results in a variable.

6) the use of `try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in)) { ...` instead of `Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);`. A `Scanner` object must always have its `close()` method called to clean up resources. In older Java versions this was achieved using try{}finally{} statements, but later versions allow this syntax (try-with-resources statement) if the class implements the AutoCloseable interface. This means the close() method is guaranteed to always get called.

7) Last but not least: the use of `int` and `Integer`, which I did not change. As suggested in the comments by @indivisible, you should be aware of [data type limitations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). An `int` can only hold numbers represented by 31 bits + sign (-2^31 -1 to 2^31), which limits this code to 16!, after which results become erroneous. If you wish to generate bigger numbers you should use `long`/`Long`. Anyway, again out of scope of this question really.

Have fun :)